# Replacing string by boolean in a JSON string?

Tags: php, json

Consider the following JSON data as string

```
'{"prop0":"true", "prop1":
    [
       {"prop0":"false", "prop1":"true", "prop2":
          [
             {"prop0":"false"}
          ]
       }
     ]
 }'
```

This structure is dynamic and could have a lot more nodes, children etc. This is how my backend receives this "unclean" JSON data (that is in fact a string). For performance matters, I'm trying to avoid to parse to a JSON obj and cycle through every node to find is there is a string that can be converted to boolean.

I know how to do that, I'm just wondering if there would be a "magical" solution to replace "true" by true **inside the string**, something like

```
str_replace("true", true, $data);
```

That obviously won't work. All I need after all is to remove the quotes around the boolean value. Does anyone know of a quick way to do that?

Comment: How is this JSON string generated  ? can`t you generate properly/

Comment: str_replace(true, true, $data)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you were very close with your `str_replace` attempt. This should do what you're looking for:

```
str_replace('"true"', 'true', $data);
```

Comment: ah indeed that works :) I'll validate in a few minutes